# Partial completeness relation for Dirac spinors

Tags: particle-physics, spinors, dirac-matrices, trace, matrix-elements

in studying trace techniques to obtain matrix elements, I came across a problem when we treat scattering of neutrinos on protons. Indeed, since those neutrinos are supposedly created in a weak decay, they are all left-handed. This means that, when taking the sum of all the spins, we do not sum on the two spins for the neutrino.

Usually, we use the relation $\sum_s u^s\overline{u}^s= \gamma^{\mu}p_\mu+m$ where s stands for the spin state (up or down). This can be proven either by explicitely solving Dirac's equation using the Pauli representation of the matrice, either by using the representation-free method illustrated here :
https://arxiv.org/pdf/physics/0703214.pdf .

Now, I'm trying to see if there is a representation free notation for $u^{up}\overline{u}^{up}$. I'm ok with **deriving** it with a representation dependent method, but I'd like a result that is representation free to be able to use it with the trace techniques.

I have found some more information : if we take $\frac{S_z+1}{2}(\gamma^{\mu}p_{\mu}+m$ then it is equal to $u^{up}\overline{u}^{up}$ because it's action on $u^s,v^s$ for $s=(up,down)$ is the same. So the problem that remains is to express $S_z$ as a function of the gamma matrices, if that's possible.

Comment: what is $S_z$? is it the generator of rotations? (in that case, $S_z=\frac{i}{4}[\gamma_1,\gamma_2]$, as usual)

Comment: Indeed, $S_z$ is the genereator of rotations, and I just figured it's relation to the gamma matrices. Maybe should have thought a bit before asking !

Comment: no worries. Remember that if you found the answer yourself, you are encouraged to post the answer below so that it can become useful for future readers. Thank you for your collaboration :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer. We will use from the paper linked that $\overline{u}^su^{s'} = 2m\delta^{ss'}$ and $\overline{u}^sv^{s'} = 0$. We also know that the operator $\gamma^{\mu}p_{\mu}+m$ "selects" particle spinors in the sense that $(\gamma^{\mu}p_{\mu}+m)u^s = 2mu^s$ and $(\gamma^{\mu}p_{\mu}+m)v^s = 0$.

We know also, using the relations from the paper that $u^{up}\overline{u}^{up}$ yields 0 on every spinor except $u^{up}$, for which it yields $2m$.

We find then that all we have to do is first select the particle spinor, and then select the spin up part of it. This is simply done by concatening the two operators, yielding : 
$u^{up}\overline{u}^{up} = \frac{\Sigma_z+1}{2}(\gamma^{\mu}p_{\mu}+m)$. Here $\Sigma_z$ is the extended pauli matrix, defined by $\Sigma_z u^{up} = u^{up}$, $\Sigma_z u^{down} = -u^{down}$ and inversely for antiparticle spinors. All is left to do is to express this in terms of the gamma matrices only. This is simply done by noticing $\Sigma_z = i\gamma^1\gamma^2$.

Hence, the answer is : $u^{up}\overline{u}^{up} = \frac{i\gamma^1\gamma^2+1}{2}(\gamma^{\mu}p_{\mu}+m)$. And it can be verified, as expected that $u^{up}\overline{u}^{up}+u^{down}\overline{u}^{down} = (\gamma^{\mu}p_{\mu}+m)$

Comment: why $\frac{\Sigma_z+1}{2}(\not p+m)$ and not $(\not p+m)\frac{\Sigma_z+1}{2}$? in other words, how do we know what is the correct ordering of the projectors?

Comment: If we compare the action of the two orderings, it would seem that the two operators are the same. I cannot seem to be able to show it by commutation relation however... There is definitely something fishy here

Comment: yes, that's what I thought... and in general $\Sigma_z$ and $\not p$ do not commute. Maybe the correct expression is with $\boldsymbol p\cdot\boldsymbol \Sigma$ instead of $\Sigma_z$?

Comment: Indeed, we would then use the completeness relations for helicities, instead of spins. It would then be $\frac{\boldsymbol p\cdot\boldsymbol \Sigma}{p}$ instead of $\Sigma_z$. But does the helicity commute with $\not p$ ?In any case, we should be able to use either of them, so a formula should be possible in both case, right ?

Comment: off the top of my head, I don't know if the helicity matrix commutes with $\not p$, but it seems to me that it should. After all, it commutes with the Dirac Hamiltonian (because helicity is conserved) and it also commutes with $\gamma^0$, and therefore I guess that it commutes with $\not p$.

Comment: I think I have figured it out : you are absolutely right, we should use helicity (it does commute with $\not p$, I verified it). So that works. The reason we cannot use the spin is because, for a non zero momentum, then the solutions of the free-particle Dirac equation cannot be eigenstates of spin too, because of the non zero commutators. Hence the use of $\Sigma_z$ is wrong ! However in the case I was considering the momentum of the neutrino was along z, so the formula simplifies to the spin case. I will correct the solution, thanks !